# Binance API get_ticker() data

Tags: python, api, binance

I am having trouble figuring out what the last three numbers returned by Binance's [`get_ticker()`](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#binance.client.Client.get_ticker) mean:

```
{
    "priceChange": "-94.99999800",
    "priceChangePercent": "-95.960",
    "weightedAvgPrice": "0.29628482",
    "prevClosePrice": "0.10002000",
    "lastPrice": "4.00000200",
    "bidPrice": "4.00000000",
    "askPrice": "4.00000200",
    "openPrice": "99.00000000",
    "highPrice": "100.00000000",
    "lowPrice": "0.10000000",
    "volume": "8913.30000000",
    "openTime": 1499783499040,
    "closeTime": 1499869899040,
    "fristId": 28385,   # First tradeId
    "lastId": 28460,    # Last tradeId
    "count": 76         # Trade count
}
```

Comment: It seems you want us to do your duty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the [docs](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#24hr-ticker-price-change-statistics) of the Binance API. After all, what `get_ticker` does, is `GET /api/v1/ticker/24hr`. As you can see, those values come from the API. Now, as the docs say, such ticker is a **24 hour rolling window price change statistics** so, `firstId` and `lastId` are the IDs of the first and last trades made in such period and `count` indicates how many trades occured in such time.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn´t able to figure it out. You know, learning python a week ago and barely knowing what an API is, doesn´t help. Having 17 years old and living in a development country neither :(